# Haskell Lens composition of ?~

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

We have an operator `?~` in Lens.
We can do `a & b . c ?~ d` if `_c` is a field of `b` type. What should I use if `b` has a `Maybe (type of _c)` type?

Comment: There are at least two different semantics this could have; please clarify the question with examples (and type signatures).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

`[Just (Just 1, 'a')] & _head . _Just . _1 ?~ 2`

Comment: Yey! Thanks a lot!